# firebase listen most recent 10 item at a path without losing 10th item when a new child is added

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to listen to the first number of nodes on a certain path.

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(10).on('value')
...
```

This was what I used originally however in this case when a new child is added to the path, the listener will now include the newest child instead. Which results on the 11th node not being updated anymore.

The solution I came up with is to grab the first node's id prior to the listener setup. So I can listen to the initial 10 post and include the newcomers with another child_added listener.

```
ref.orderByKey().endAt(threshold).limitToLast(10)
```

However, this approach requires me to detach the current listener and set up a new one every time I intend to reach out more nodes than the initial count. (Which is required for just a basic pull to load more function)

```
oldref.off()
ref.orderByKey().endAt(threshold).limitToLast(20)
```

This approach works, but I feel like it over complicates the code so I wonder if anyone has a better approach in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is simple: use `"child_added"` instead of `"value"`

```
var items = [];
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(10).on("child_added", (snap) => {
    items.push(snap);
});

// To load more do this
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(20).endAt(items[0].key).once("value")
```

This way you will immediately get last 10 items one-by-one and then each new item

Comment: The issue is I want to implement a load more function. I can initialize the listener as limitToLast(10) as you recommend but things get a little sketchy when I detach this listener and set up a new one as limitToLast(20)

Comment: Would the items[0].key always be the actual first element?

Comment: @Thasd try and see if it works :D If not, use last. You may need to improve this code for your actual case

Comment: Thanks the approach might work and I think the order will workout fine as well. My only concern is that I will probably end up putting a new value listener to every single child I grabbed like this because I need the data updated. Then there ends up being so many listeners floating around and that becomes somewhat hard to manage :P